# Floating point equivalent to strtol() in C

Tags: c, binary, radix, strtol

`strtol` converts the inputed string str to a long value of any specified base of 2 to 36. `strtof()` offers a similar functionality but without allowing your to specify base. Is there another function that does the same as `strtof` but allows you to select base?

e.g Lets say 101.101 is inputted as a string. I want to be able to do

```
strtof("101.101", null, 2);
```

and get an output of `5.625.`

Comment: Can you show an example of the floating point value to convert?

Comment: You can simply convert the part before and after the '.' using strtol and then making a float out of both

Comment: @ZachP That works for numbers before the decimal point but what about numbers after?

Comment: @ChristopherClarke I've wrote this in an answer, it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the string to split it in the `.` and convert the part before and the part after to decimal. Afterwards, you can create a float out of that string. Here is a simple function that accomplishes that.

```
float new_strtof(char* const ostr, char** endptr, unsigned char base)
{
    char* str = (char*)malloc(strlen(ostr) + 1);
    strcpy(str, ostr);
    const char* dot = ".";

    /* I do not validate any input here, nor do I do anything with endptr */      //Let's assume input of 101.1101, null, 2 (binary)
    char *cbefore_the_dot = strtok(str, dot); //Will be 101
    char *cafter_the_dot = strtok(NULL, dot); //Will be 0101

    float f = (float)strtol (cbefore_the_dot, 0, base); //Base would be 2 = binary. This would be 101 in decimal which is 5
    int i, sign = (str[0] == '-'? -1 : 1);
    char n[2] = { 0 }; //will be just for a digit at a time

    for(i = 0 ; cafter_the_dot[i] ; i++) //iterating the fraction string
    {
        n[0] = cafter_the_dot[i];
        f += strtol(n, 0, base) * pow(base, -(i + 1)) * sign; //converting the fraction part
    }

    free(str);
    return f;
}
```

One could manage this in a more efficient and less dirty way but this is just an example to show you the idea behind this. The above works well for me.

Don't forget to `#include <math.h>` and compile with `-lm` flag. An example would be `gcc file.c -o file -lm`.

Comment: 101.1101 should be 5.8125, but you would get out 5.13, right? Maybe you could clear that up a bit more, what the representation of binary fractions is and how you get decimal fractions from it in your sample

Comment: And how would you handle a leading 0 for the decimal part?

Comment: @KarstenKoop You are right about that, will take care of the fraction part. What do you mean, though, about handling a leading 0? Where would it cause a problem?

Comment: the numbers 1.1 and 1.01 should not lead to the same result

Comment: @KarstenKoop Indeed, that's a problem in the fraction calculation - will fix that now

Comment: Nice simple solution! Just needed to do some slight error check on my end. Thanks @ZachP

Comment: @ChristopherClarke No problem! Don't forget that you can use double to increase accuracy

Comment: `new_strtof("-101.101", NULL, 2)` returns -4.375.  I'd expect -5.625.

Comment: @chux Fixed, tell me if there are any more problems

Comment: Certainly good enough for OP's basic goal.  Should you want an in depth review to detail the various subtle problems, post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, here's a simple, straightforward version of `atoi()`, that accepts an arbitrary base to use (i.e. not necessarily 10):

```
#include <ctype.h>

int myatoi(const char *str, int b)
{
    const char *p;
    int ret = 0;
    for(p = str; *p != '\0' && isspace(*p); p++)
        ;
    for(; *p != '\0' && isdigit(*p); p++)
        ret = b * ret + (*p - '0');
    return ret;
}
```

(Note that I have left out negative number handling.)

Once you've got that, it's straightforward to detect a decimal point and handle digits to the right of it as well:

```
double myatof(const char *str, int b)
{
    const char *p;
    double ret = 0;
    for(p = str; *p != '\0' && isspace(*p); p++)
        ;
    for(; *p != '\0' && isdigit(*p); p++)
        ret = b * ret + (*p - '0');

    if(*p == '.')
        {
        double fac = b;
        for(p++; *p != '\0' && isdigit(*p); p++)
            {
            ret += (*p - '0') / fac;
            fac *= b;
            }
        }

    return ret;
}
```

A slightly less obvious approach, which might be numerically better behaved, is:

```
double myatof2(const char *str, int b)
{
    const char *p;
    long int n = 0;
    double denom = 1;
    for(p = str; *p != '\0' && isspace(*p); p++)
        ;
    for(; *p != '\0' && isdigit(*p); p++)
        n = b * n + (*p - '0');

    if(*p == '.')
        {
        for(p++; *p != '\0' && isdigit(*p); p++)
            {
            n = b * n + (*p - '0');
            denom *= b;
            }
        }

    return n / denom;
}
```

I tested these with

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", myatoi("123", 10));
    printf("%d\n", myatoi("10101", 2));

    printf("%f\n", myatof("123.123", 10));
    printf("%f\n", myatof("101.101", 2));

    printf("%f\n", myatof2("123.123", 10));
    printf("%f\n", myatof2("101.101", 2));

    return 0;
}
```

which prints

```
123
21
123.123000
5.625000
123.123000
5.625000
```

as expected.

One more note: these functions don't handle bases greater than 10.

Answer (score 0):

Calculations with FP can incur accumulated round off errors and other subtleties.  The below simply calculates the whole number part and the fractional part as 2 base-n integers and then, with minimally FP calculation, derives the answer.

Code also needs to cope with a negative whole number part and insure the fractional part is treated with the same sign.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double CC_strtod(const char *s, char **endptr, int base) {
  char *end;
  if (endptr == NULL) endptr = &end;
  long ipart = strtol(s, endptr, base);
  if ((*endptr)[0] == '.') {
    (*endptr)++;
    char *fpart_start = *endptr;
    // Insure `strtol()` is not fooled by a space, + or - 
    if (!isspace((unsigned char) *fpart_start) && 
        *fpart_start != '-' && *fpart_start != '+') {
      long fpart = strtol(fpart_start, endptr, base);
      if (ipart < 0) fpart = -fpart;
      return fma(fpart, pow(base, fpart_start - *endptr), ipart);
    }
  }
  return ipart;
}

int main() {
  printf("%e\n", CC_strtod("101.101", NULL, 2));
}
```

Output

```
5.625000e+00
```

The above is limited in that the two parts should not exceed the range of `long`.  Code could use wider types like `intmax_t` for a less restrictive function.